# Power estimation

Tags: parameter-estimation

I have data from two channels, $A$ and $B$. The first contains a signal of interest, $s[n]$, plus some additive white Gaussian noise, and the second contains a scaled (real, non-negative) copy of my signal of interest and noise with different variance (different noise power).

\begin{align}
a[n] &=   s[n] + N_a[n]\\
b[n] &= m \cdot s[n] + N_b[n]
\end{align}

I don't know $s[n]$, but assume it is mean zero, and I don't know the noise powers, but they are comparable or slightly higher than the signal power.

- Is it possible to get an unbiased estimate of $m$?
- If so, how?
- If not, how could I prove that?

If I could estimate the variance on $N_a$, the following would work:

$$ \hat{m} = \frac{\sum_n b[n]a^*[n]}{\sum_n a[n]a^*[n] - \sum_n \sigma^2_{N_a} } $$

(edit: correction due to robert bristow-johnson - I need the ratio of the sum, not the sum of ratio)

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Interesting question. Can you be sure there is no delay between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Yes, there is no significant delay.

Comment: What are the characteristics of the WGN? Do both have zero mean and some variance?

Comment: Don't think I can prove it, but my feeling is that you need to know at least the variance of the signal, and perhaps the additive noise also.

Comment: Yes, the noise is zero mean Gaussian, but I don't know the variance unless it can be estimated from $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing the notation to something better, i think the summations have to go in both the numerator and denominator:

$$ \hat{m} = \frac{\sum_n b[n]a^*[n]}{\sum_n a[n]a^*[n] - \sum_n \sigma^2_{N_a} }
 $$

---

This is a plot showing:

- The variation in choosing different $\sigma_{N_a}^2$ values from the true value. The true value is shown by the red line.

  - Upshot: always **under** estimate it, or just choose it to be zero.
- The true value of $m$ in green vs various $b/a$ values from @Peter K.'s answer.
- The estimates for 100 runs of both estimators. Blue is this estimator, green is the middle quintile of the $b/a$ values.

  - For this particular run, the variance of this estimator was 0.03013508; the $b/a$ estimator's was 0.04913840.

**Bottom line:** Use this estimator with $\sigma_{N_a}^2 = 0$.

[image]

---

**R Code Below**

```
# 30639
N <- 1000

s <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)

sigma_a <- 0.1
sigma_b <- 0.2

na <- rnorm(N,0,sigma_a)
nb <- rnorm(N,0,sigma_b)

m <- 10

a <- s + na
b <- m*s  + nb

ix <- 1

test_values <- seq(0,sigma_b*4,0.001)
mhat <- 0*test_values
for (test_sigma_b in test_values)
{  
  mhat[ix] <- sum(b * a)/(sum(a*a) - N*test_sigma_b*test_sigma_b)
  ix <- ix + 1
}

par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(test_values, mhat, ylim=c(-10,20), type="l")
lines(c(sigma_b, sigma_b), c(-10,20), col="red");
title('Effect of varying sigma_b')

plot(b/a,  pch=10, col="grey", ylim=c(-10,20))
lines(c(1,N), c(m, m), type="l", col="green", lwd=10)
#lines(c(1,N), c(mhat, mhat), type="l", col="blue", lwd=5)
title('True m value vs b/a estimate')

Nruns <- 100
mhat_1 <- rep(0,Nruns)
mhat_2 <- rep(0,Nruns)

for (run_number in seq(1,Nruns))
{
  s_run <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
  a_run <- s_run + rnorm(N,0,sigma_a)
  b_run <- m * s_run + rnorm(N,0,sigma_b)

  mhat_1[run_number] <- sum(b_run * a_run)/sum(a_run*a_run)
  mhat_2[run_number] <- quantile(b_run/a_run)[3]
}

sds <- c(sd(mhat_1), sd(mhat_2))
print(sds)

plot(mhat_1, type="l", col="blue")
lines(mhat_2, col="green")
title('BLUE: rb-j estimate GREEN: middle quintile of b/a estimate')
```

Comment: i think if you don't know the variance of the additive noise, $\sigma^2_{N_a}$, then you have no choice but a biased estimator.

Comment: Why $a*$? Is $a$ complex?

Comment: i presume it could be.  maybe even $m$ is complex.  OP used that note.

Comment: $s(t)$ (or $s[n]$) might be complex.

Comment: Yours is the best estimator I've found, but I'm still left trying to guess $\sigma^2_{N_a}$.   Is there any other way around it?

Comment: The value of $m$ is real, if that helps.  I've been treating the other variables as complex, but I don't think that adds or removes anything.  I could break the equations into real and imaginary parts (both with $m$ in them), and then I would have 4 equations.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson : I've added a real-valued only examination of this. It seems to work nicely, and selection of $\sigma_{N_a}^2 = 0$ seems to work well enough.

Comment: robert bristow-johnson and Peter K., I appreciate the effort you guys put into this, but assuming $\sigma^2_{N_a}=0$ isn't really right.  For now, I'm going to assume that $\sigma^2_{N_a}=\sigma^2_{N_b}$ and solve the quadratic equation for the _common_ noise term (even though it isn't really common).  I've marked this answer correct, regardless.  Cheers, and thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious approach is to just do
$$
\hat{m} = b[n] / a[n]
$$
for any particular $n$.

Note that because $a$ and $b$ are Gaussian, the division will be Cauchy distributed. Unfortunately, averaging Cauchy random variables does not improve the variance, so doing
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b[n] / a[n]
$$
won't improve the estimate.

Comment: This approach works at very high SNR, but falls apart at low to moderate SNR for the reasons you mention.

Comment: Minor comment: the $1/T$ is not needed.

Comment: i don't normally edit Peter's posts.  but i wish we would clearly differentiate the notation for discrete-time signals (for which we apply summation) from continuous-time signals (for which we apply integration).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson make that a meta post.  Definitely worth considering $[n]$ for discrete and $(t)$ for continuous. I've seen both used for both in texts and papers, but I know it confuses.

Comment: okay.  the bracket thing is newer and the first i saw it was O&S (the orange one).  there *were* DSP texts that used the standard math notation for discrete sequences (i.e. $x_n$), but the problem was when we would get a vector of signals in continuous-time, $x_k(t)$.  if sampled, $x_k(nT)$, how was that notation nicely converted to a sequence.  $x_{kn}$ was not good and $x_k(n)$ was also not good.

Comment: @WhoKnows Why isn't $\frac{1}{T}$ needed?

Comment: I was wrong - the $1/T$ is important in your version, but I got the ratio of the sums in my head instead of the sum of the ratios...  My bad.